# How to extract Upper case words (with at least two letters)

Tags: excel, vba

I need to extract last names, which are allways written upper case, from cells, where is written all the name. The name can have different shapes e.g.:

- Jan H. NOVAK
- Petr Karel POUZAR
- Frantisek Ix GREGOR

I have tried to find some VBAs on the web. I found this one, but it extract also the one letter middle names which are also upper case:

```
Function UpperWords(str As Variant) As String
Dim i As Integer, sTemp As String, StrTmp As String
For i = 0 To UBound(Split(str, " "))
  StrTmp = Split(str, " ")(i)
  If UCase(StrTmp) = StrTmp Then sTemp = sTemp & " " & StrTmp
Next i
UpperWords = Trim(sTemp)
End Function
```

I need to define in the VBA tahat the upper case word which I want to extract has at least two letters.

Thank you for your ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the test to the `If`:

```
Function UpperWords(str As Variant) As String
    Dim i As Integer, sTemp As String, StrTmp As String
    For i = 0 To UBound(Split(str, " "))
      StrTmp = Split(str, " ")(i)
      If UCase(StrTmp) = StrTmp And Len(StrTmp) > 1 Then sTemp = sTemp & " " & StrTmp
    Next i
    UpperWords = Trim(sTemp)
End Function
```

Comment: Hi, it works with the condition Len(StrTmp) > 2.
"." was also counted to the length of the string.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to ***extract last names***, then you can use a formula/function to do just that.  Capitalization would seem to be irrelevant.

**worksheet formula**

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",REPT(" ",99)),99))
```

**UDF**

```
Function lastName(S As String) As String
    lastName = Mid(S, InStrRev(Trim(S), " ") + 1)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim regEx As Object
Dim allMatches As Object
Dim Surname As Variant
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim m As Match

Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A4")

For Each cell In rng

    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With regEx
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .Pattern = "\s([A-Z]+)$"
        .Global = True
    End With

    Set allMatches = regEx.Execute(cell.Value)
    For Each m In allMatches
        Surname = m.SubMatches(0)
        Debug.Print Surname
    Next

Next cell
```